# Bootstrap fixed container with parent width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I'm developing a web with bootstrap 3.0 and it has the following structure:

```
- Sidebar: width 220px, position fixed and top:0
- Content: margin-left:220px (Because of the sidebar width).
     - Topbar: position fixed and top 0
```

The problem is that the fixed topbar doesn't get parent width, you can see my css in this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fzgot

The topbar is on .main-content header {}
As you can see I added width:inherit, but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you are after?
http://www.bootply.com/75880

I added

```
width:100%;
max-width:760px; /* set max width as req'd */
```

to the .main-content header section

Comment: I can't add max-width because It must fit the rest of the document

Comment: @SergiFrom, no problem, simply add width:100%; and you'll be good

Comment: I tried this before, but look what happens with the "red search panel" http://codepen.io/sergiolopezevermic/pen/zwHgF